When speaking of a language is countability of nouns a 'concept' or a 'notion' or something else?

Does the Russian language have the concepts/notions of “countable”
and “uncountable”?

Which should I use, concepts or notions?

Please change the title, otherwise you'll get people thinking this is a question about the Russian language.

@StuartF Do you have a suggestion?

This might be dialect dependent.  I am a well educated native speaker of English; and unlike Jasper, I would find "notions" more idiomatic than "concepts" in this context.

Thank you very much, @DawoodibnKareem. I'd like to know why you find "notions" more idiomatic. Is that because there are many languages in which nouns don't inflect?

Honestly, the two words "notion" and "concept" are so very close in meaning that I don't think any difference is worth worrying about.  I am equally comfortable reading either in this context.  If I were writing such a sentence myself, I'd more likely choose "notion"; for no particularly good reason.  It just seems slightly more natural to me.

Many thanks, @DawoodibnKareem.

"[C]oncepts" is idiomatic in this example.
"Notion" has connotations of "novelty", "new idea", "idea that is not widely held", or "idea that has not stood the test of time".  In other words, it has connotations of being non-standard or weird.
Whereas this example is asking about a conventional way of interpreting the grammar of a language.

The Wikipedia articles count noun and mass noun both use the word "concept".

Thank you very much, @StuartF. Now I think I should have used "(un)countable nouns" or "(un)countability" instead of "(un)countable".

Your phrasing in the example is fine.  A concept can be verbalized using an adjective.  For example, the idea that something can be "hairy" is a concept.

Thank you very much, @Jasper.
